# What is the difference, if any, between the global namespace and the default namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

The diversity of names related to namespaces is intersected in a way that I need additional clarification on.

The default namespace, base namespace, unnamed namespace, root namespace, and global namespace are all examples of namespaces.

All of these are used interchangeably, making them hard to follow.

I've come up with a guess (and correct me if I'm wrong) that:

1. The concept of a default namespace (also known as a base namespace) is related to Visual Studio. When a new class is created by VS, it will automatically be wrapped within the default namespace. This is just to save developers' time.
2. The global namespace (also known as an unnamed namespace or root namespace), on the other hand, is primarily a C# concept. And it is a container for types and namespaces that have no enclosing brackets.

Thanks.

**Update 1: Places where these terms occurred**

[image]

> The compiler adds a **default namespace**. This **unnamed namespace**, sometimes referred to as the **global namespace**, is present in every file. It contains declarations not included in a declared namespace. Any identifier in the global namespace is available for use in a named namespace. [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace)
>
> The global namespace is the "root" namespace: global::System will always refer to the .NET System namespace.[[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/namespaces)

Comment: Out of all the terms related to "namespace" you mentioned, only "global namespace" is defined in the C# spec. Where did you see these other terms?

Comment: @Sweeper -- Yes, I have added additional resources to the question.

Comment: What about "base namespace" and "root namespace"?

Comment: `RootNamespace` is a setting in the project's csproj file, which i think is equivalent to the RootNamespaceAttribute, and which the project configuration UI of Visual Studio however calls "default namespace"